# Is Grails a good choice to develop a web application that works against Cassandra?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, grails, cassandra

The startup company I work in is facing a difficult technology decision these days.
We're about to develop a web application that is supposed to handle lots of financial transactions. After a long research we did, we found Cassandra as the best fit for our needs, and we're tending to write the backend in Java.

The thing is that we're not sure about the frontend itself. We're getting the feeling that Grails is good for us in terms of learning curve and productivity, but we're not sure how good it is with Cassandra, and..in general, is it a good choice comparing to Spring MVC that we're more familiar with, Ruby on Rails, PHP etc.

We would really appreciate your opinion about it, and of course will be more than thankful to hear any comments about our thinking of writing the backend in Java (although I know we didn't write much about our application).

Thanks ahead to all of you!
A fan of stackoverflow.com :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal grails terminology there is a plugin for that

https://github.com/wolpert/grails-cassandra

Now I don't have any experience with cassandra but I've done a couple of grails apps that handle large amounts of data and I've had good success with each.

the big one is PIMS

http://news.xerox.com/pr/xerox/new-web-based-tool-for-xerox-igen4-production-information-management-system.aspx

This one is actually probably close to what you are actually doing.
it uses grails, jquery, jquery-ui on the client side and then there is a lot of java back end mixed with grails/groovy logic

it handles the a log of back end java logic with out any problems.

the hardest thing to get right is the database...but you will run into that with what ever technology you decide to use